# Restoring IOS 8 doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I have a tabbed application with 2 storyboards. In the 2nd storyboard I have a restoration-ID.
I implemented the following in the AppDelegate:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
```

---

and this in my SecondViewController:

```
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.myTextView.text forKey:@"unsavedText"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self.myTextView.text=[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"unsavedText"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

---

But when i go to Home with iOS simulator , stop the running application and restart, the TextView doesn't restore text, my application starts in a first tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have missed assigning a restoration ID elsewhere in your view hierarchy.

Did you also change your AppDelegate from `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?

There are some useful state restoration tools available at the [Downloads for Apple Developers](http://developer.apple.com/downloads/.) page.

Search for *restoration* to find a debug profile which logs your app's state restoration to the console, as well as the restorationArchiveTool to dump the state restoration data in human-readable format.

Comment: io non assegnato Id Restauro in RootViewController, now run!

Comment: Were you able to get the debug profile working on an iOS 8 device?  I get "Profile Installation Failed: The profile "State Restoration Developer Mode" is no longer valid" on an 8.0.2 and 8.1 device.

Comment: @MichaelMcGuire Also can't get the profiles to install. I found a workaround by adding the `UIStateRestorationDeveloperMode` and `UIStateRestorationDebugLogging` keys to .GlobalPreferences.plist in the `Library/Preferences/` directory of the simulator.

Comment: @Niels that's fantastic!  Should help with debugging, although I really need the Developer mode set on a device for testing purposes by my client.

Comment: I should mention that I filed a radar on this: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5600741037178880